# Delayed trigger for Backbone on Nodejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, q, rxjs

```
B = require 'backbone'
U = require 'underscore'

o = {}
U.extend o, B.Events
o.on 'e', console.log
setTimeout o.trigger, 5000, 'e', 'Hi!'
```

Why did `Nodejs` console not log for the delayed Backbone `#trigger` above?

#### @Edit

```
Q = require 'q'

d = Q.defer()
d.promise.then console.log
setTimeout d.resolve, 5000, 'Hi!'
```

This worked flawlessly. But why did the console not log if Q `#resolve` was wrapped in the anonymous function below,

```
setTimeout (-> d.resolve 'Hi!'), 5000
```

#### @Edit 2

Actually the wrapped version Q `#resolve` also worked if being invoked at first and once.

Why the plain version Q `#resolve` worked while Backbone `#trigger` didn't, is the only remaining question.

#### @Edit 3

```
R = require 'rx'

src = new R.BehaviorSubject 0
dst = src.map (v) -> v + 1
dst.subscribe console.log
setTimeout src.onNext, 5000, 1
```

Rx `#onNext` had similar problem and solution to Backbone `#trigger`.

All above can be sourced to the varying `this` context, e.g. a bare version shows the problem below,

```
o =
    f: ->
    g: -> @f()

setTimeout o.g
```

then,

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'f'
```

The wrapped version below thus goes through.

```
setTimeout -> o.g()
```

Below shows `this` context switch to cause the problem and the wrapper to solve it,

```
f = (g) -> g.apply @

o = 
    x: 'Hi!'
    g: -> console.log @x

f o.g # undefined
f -> o.g() # 'Hi!'
```

#### @Edit 4

Additionally, Coffeescript `=>` binding to `this` varies to `->` below,

```
x = 'Hi!'
o = f: => @x

console.log o.f() # Hi!
console.log -> o.f() # undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you pass `o.trigger` as an argument to `setTimeout` you execute `trigger` function not as an method for `o` object but instead you execute it in global scope. That is in this case `this` inside `trigger` will point not to `o` but to `global` object.

So before passing `o.trigger` as an argument to `setTimeout` you need to wrap it in anonymous function.

Unfortunately I'm not good in Coffee Script but I can show you how your code should look like in pure JavaScript:

```
var B, U, o;

B = require('backbone');
U = require('underscore');

o = {};

U.extend(o, B.Events);

o.on('e', console.log);

setTimeout(function () {
    o.trigger('e', 'Hi!');
}, 5000);
```

Hope this will help. Good luck.

Comment: @sof as I said earlier my knowledge of Coffee Script is pretty poor, also I've never worked with q or rx libraries. So I'm afraid I just have no time for digging in all this stuff.